# AWS S3 Requester Pays Does not work with TransferManager

Tags: java, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager, s3transfermanager

I am trying to use [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) class in my java program to download a file from a [Requester Pays Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html).
I am getting "Status Code: 403" exception from amazon AWS.
I wrote a simple program to test this feature and compare it single connection way of downloading a file. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import com.amazonaws.auth.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.*;
import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;
public class RequesterPaysTest {
    final static AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(MY IAMAccessKey,MY IAMSecretKey);
    final static String bucketName = "7268982505fe.mixnode.com";
    final static String fileName = "5379-7268982505fe-0-1496081968663.warc.gz";
    final static AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider =  new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);
    final static AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider).withRegion(MY bucketRegion).build();
    final static GetObjectRequest getRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, true);

    static void testSimpleRequesterPays() {
        try {
        S3Object object = s3client.getObject(getRequest);
        InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (new File(fileName));
        IOUtils.copy(objectData, out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println(" Simple RequesterPays successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" Simple RequesterPays unsuccessful: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    static void testTransferManagerRequesterPays() {
        try {
            TransferManager tx = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3client).build();
            Download download = tx.download(getRequest, new File(fileName));
            while (download.isDone() == false)
                Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.println(" TransferManager RequesterPays successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" TransferManager RequesterPays unsuccessful: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    testSimpleRequesterPays();
    testTransferManagerRequesterPays();
}
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Simple RequesterPays successful
 TransferManager RequesterPays unsuccessful: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 77D5EBF5EE195A7A)
```

As you can see, the same file can be downloaded using simple method but not with TransferManager. I tried to create my own bucket and played around with permissions but it did not work.
I was wondering if I miss anything in my code? Or whether AWS s3 does not have support for using TransferManager on a requester pays bucket?

Answer (score 0):

TransferManager internally using http **HEAD** method instead of **GET** for downloading objects(file(s)). You can find it by debugging TransferManager SDK code. If you don't have  **HEAD** method configuration in your aws api gateway, you have to create **HEAD** method configuration to match with TransferManager SDK code. By the way if resource not found it should give 404 but you are getting 403. reason is here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216684